# WHM new account nameservers not responding

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, nameserver

I've setup a new account in WHM and updated the nameservers from Domain Registrar and it's not responding from the server.

So I went to DNS functions and Nameserver IP's and I have the following

```
ns1.example.com.au  No IP   4
ns2.example.com.au  No IP   4
```

I'm not sure whether "NO IP" part is the problem

I went in to the domains and they seem to be properly set up. Below is what my Domain Registrar responded with my ticket.

```
those nameservers are either a) offline/not responding or b) not set up correctly as nameservers.
```

Is there a place I can check in WHM to make nameservers respond correctly? The nameservers I updated with above ns1.example.com.au and ns2.example.com.au but it's not working.

WHM version is: WHM 11.32.2 (build 18)

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the DNS zone of WHM for this domain name and add following A record entries:

ns1 A IP address1
ns2 A IP address2

Once you  do this, you can login to domain name registrar and first register these nameservers as child nameservers (Private nameservers) and then only you can use these nameservers as main nameservers for any other domain names you host in your server.